# Обработка событий мыши в 3д моделях

Tags: wpf, 3d, c#

Исходные условия: имеется 3д сцена, состоящая из множества элементов. Все элементы сцены упакованы в Model3dGroup контейнеры, и хранятся в ресурсах. В качестве контейнера для сцены используется Viewport3D, в котором к получаемой из ресурсов сцене добавляются камера и освещение.

Вопрос заключается в следующем: как распознать, по какому элементу сцены происходит, например, клик мыши? PS Как отлавливать события мыши для всей сцены понятно.Хотелось бы сделать это стандартными средствами WPF

Answer (score 2):

К сожалению, вам придётся вручную просчитывать то место, куда случился клик. Вам придётся "провести линию", перпендикулярную плоскости камеры через точку, в которую произошёл клик мыши, а затем найти всех, кто пересекает эту линию. После этого, найденных надо отсортировать по расстоянию до точки пересечения вашей линии и плоскости камеры. Не забыть также отсеять объекты "за спиной". Копайте в сторону gamedev-статей. С ходу нашёл такие:

http://www.gamedev.ru/code/forum/?id=50092
http://www.gamedev.ru/code/forum/?id=86652
http://www.gamedev.ru/code/forum/?id=17370

Comment: Ну относительно объектов на проведенной линии все несколько проще: именно в данной сцене все объекты расположены в одной плоскости, перпендикулярно которой и выставлена камера(как бы фронтальный вид).
Мб в связи с этим есть более простые способы?

Comment: Всё равно придётся проецировать. Это допущение позволит упростить формулы :) Кстати, они зависят от того, какое у вас проецирование. Я не знаток DirectX, но в OpenGL есть несколько стандартных вариантов (ортогональная, перспективная...) и в зависимости от этого может возинкнуть разница в расчётах. Думаю, в DX тоже есть подобная опасность.

Comment: Я тоже не знаток DX, но когда-то по надобности написал на нём парочку программ. Там есть специальные функции, которые берут координату мыши, сами проводят луч как надо и возвращают объект, в который луч уткнулся. Ну это так, воспоминания какие-то…

Comment: В каком виде они интересно возвращают объект? Как его опознать, если всё что есть, это по большей части массивы вершин и их свойств?

Comment: Большинство функций такого типа основаны на поиске пересечения луча (прямой) и треугольника. И выдают барицентрические координаты точки пересечения если она есть. А программисту придется самому позаботиться чтобы понять к какому объекту этот треугольник принадлежит. Но это не сложно, так как в любом случае сначала целесообразно отсекать части сцены по огибающим объемам (OOB/AAB/сфере), треугольники тех объектов что прошли отсечение перебираются последовательно и сортируются (отбрасываются) по дальности. Стало быть всегда известно в каком объекте мы нашли пересечение.

Answer (score 0):

Viewport3dVisual2d позволяет разместить контролы на 3d сцене. К контролам можно привязать обработчики событий.